# parent.window.location.pathname returning undefined?

Tags: javascript

```
if ( parent.window.location.pathname.indexOf ( "login" ) > 0 )
    var selfUrl = 'http://www.example.com';
else
    var selfUrl = unescape(parent.window.location.pathname);
```

This is a redirect for a login issue, but parent.window.location.pathname is returning undefined.

Weirder still, we run the same code on our dev server and it all works kosher like. Same browsers, same code.

Comment: Are you sure the document which you're calling that function from has a `parent`? That is, are you executing that code from inside an `iframe` or similar? Try without both `parent`s.

Comment: The pathname still shouldn't return undefined - or at least, Chrome's console doesn't when I paste that line into it.  On the top window, `window.parent` returns itself.

Comment: One situation in which `location` could be undefined (or is it null?) is if your script doesn't have rights to access the parent window, i.e. if it's running within an iframe on another domain.

Comment: It's in an iFrame. I think I might have it though: the login window is secure, i.e. https, and the window that pops the iframe isn't.

Answer (score 0):

Is the parent window on the same domain?  If not, then you don't have rights to access `parent.location`.  I forget just how much of `location` is inaccessible in that case (I think you have no read privileges, but you might have some write privileges), but you certainly won't be able to access the pathname.

Comment: I think that might be it: the login form is secure, i.e. https, and the page calling it isn't. Any idea for a work around? We can't secure the entire site because we allow hot linked images (people can customize a page on our site, and we allow them to use images hosted outside, generally from their own website).

Comment: Yes; you can put something in the URL of the iframe indicating that it was called by the login page.  It may not take anything more than a hash (`#fromLogin`) appended to the URL, then checked for by the JavaScript on the page.